# Как сделать программу, которая по шаблону создаёт регион, а потом использует его для отсечения окна?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Хотел сделать программу, которая по шаблону создаёт регион, а потом использует его для отсечения окна. Вот код программы:

```
unit Back;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    function RegionFromFile(pict: TPicture; backcolor: TColor): HRGN;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function (pict :TPicture; backcolor: TColor): HRGN;
var
  rgn, resRgn: HRGN;
  x, y, xFirst: Integer;
begin
  resRgn := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
  for y := 0 to pict.Height - 1 do
  begin
    x := 0;
    while x < pict.Width do
    begin
       if (pict.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[x, y] <> backcolor) then
       begin
         xFirst := x;
         Inc(x);
         while (x < pict.Width) and (pict.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[x, y] <> backcolor) do Inc(x);
         rgn := CreateRectRgn(xFirst, y, x-1, y+1);
         CombineRgn(resRgn, resRgn, rgn, RGN_OR);
         DeleteObject(rgn);
       end;
       Inc(x);
    end;
  end;  
  RegionFromPicture := resRgn;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  pict: TPicture;
begin
  pict := TPicture.Create;
  pict.LoadFromFile('back.png');
  SetWindowRgn(Handle, RegionFromRicture(pict, RGB(255,255,255)), True);
end;

end.
```

P.S. Файл шаблона хранится в back.png.

Comment: В обработчике OnCreate прога ничего не нарисует, надо в обработчике OnPaint этот код писать, а ещё, похоже на то, что формат png он не понимает, надо bmp использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых неправильно это (после директивы):

```
function (pict :TPicture; backcolor: TColor): HRGN;
```

Нужно написать так:

```
function RegionFromFile(pict :TPicture; backcolor: TColor): HRGN;
```

Т. е. забыто имя функции.
Ещё в конце этой функции нужно писать её имя правильно (или писать Result):

```
RegionFromFile := resRgn;
```

Последняя строка обработчика FormCreate:

```
SetWindowRgn(Handle, RegionFromFile(pict, RGB(255,255,255)), True);
```

Сейчас попытаюсь ещё что-нибудь найти.

Comment: Компилятор почему-то при ошибке ставит мне курсор в это строке:
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
    function RegionFromFile(pict: TPicture;backcolor:TColor):HRGN;// Здесь пишет, что ошибка
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

Comment: А, вообще, функцию function RegionFromFile(pict :TPicture; backcolor: TColor): HRGN; не нужно ни в каких разделах объявлять, можно её там закомментировать.

Comment: Я пробовал компилить - у меня не пашет, почему пока не разобрался.

Comment: Программа теперь запустилась, но регион не сделала!!! То есть форма как была прямоугольной, так и осталась!!! Я уже пробовал и другие шаблоны! А всё равно не получается!!!

Comment: Скорее всего не работает функция RegionFromFile Потому что пробовал в обработчике OnCreate сделать по-другому: с помощью дополнительной переменной типа HRGN. Потом вместо 
    SetWindowRgn(Handle, RegionFromFile(pict, RGB(255,255,255)), True);
я сделал
    SetWindowRgn(Handle, Form_rgn, True);
P.S. Form_rgn - это переменная типа HRGN.

Comment: попробуйте формирование региона в OnFormShow или OnFormActivate вставить, в OnFormCreate она не срабатывает вроде, хотя не помню точно, давно было